# HTML to Open XML conversion

Tags: html, xslt, openxml, docx

I've this input HTML:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="color:#ff0000;">AA</p>
```

What is the right xslt code to create a valid open XML tree that can be used to create a valid DOCX file.

Comment: Your question is too broad because there are an infinite number of "right" stylesheets that transform your input into valid OpenXML.

Comment: can you give me just one "right" way to do that!!!

Comment: You did not explain how this HTML snippet should be processed by an XSLT processor and what should become of it in OpenXML. As long as this basic question remains unanswered, nobody can help you. Also, we do not know the environment you are using XSLT in, the version of XSLT and OpenXML, we do not see your attempt at coding this and finally, only XHTML would be a valid input to XSLT. That's too many "unknowns" to give an answer.

Comment: In general, you should not try to construct Open XML yourself, but rather use an API from a programming language such as C# to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to XSLT, you could try docx4j-ImportXHTML; see the [samples](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples). That's Java; there is an IKVM'd version if you prefer [C#/.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j-ImportXHTML.NET/) as to which see [my walkthrough](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/c-net-import-xhtml-into-docx-without-word/)

I work on that project.  I'm aware of several others, but have no experience of them.  These include: http://html2openxml.codeplex.com and http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/